# Strange printf output

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I executed the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", 9/5);
}
```

Output : `0.000000`

why not `1` ?

if i write `printf("%f %f %d %d\n", (float)9/5, 4, sizeof(float), sizeof(int));`

then output is `1.800000 0.000000 4 59`

why not `1.800000 4 4 4`

on my machine the `sizeof (float)` is `4`

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Shahbaz now that it's not tagged c++ anymore, true

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because your `printf` format specifier doesn't match what you passed it:

`9/5` is of type `int`. But `printf` expects a `float`.

So you need to either cast it to a float or make either literal a float:

```
printf("%f\n", (float)9/5);
printf("%f\n", 9./5);
```

As for why you're getting `0.0`, it's because the `printf()` is reading the binary representation of `1` (an integer) and printing it as a `float`. Which happens to be a small denormalized value that is very close to `0.0`.

**EDIT :** There's also something going with type-promotion on varargs.

In vararg functions, `float` is promoted to `double`. So `printf()` in this case actually expects a 64-bit parameter holding a `double`. But you only passed it a 32-bit operand so it's actually reading an extra 32-bits from the stack (which happens to be zero in this case) - even more undefined behavior.

Comment: And when asked for warnings, a compiler like GCC would have found that (use `gcc -Wall`)

Comment: There's no guarantee that the arguments to printf are passed on the stack (or even that there is a stack).  You don't know *what* it's reading.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: What are alternatives? Could give an example?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Undefined behavior is undefined behavior. As long as your types match the format strings, there's nothing to worry about. In C++, it's easier (and safer) to just use "cout".

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: sure, the arguments can be passed in register, as in the standard x86_64 ABI.

Comment: @Mysticial: right, undefined behavior is undefined behavior.  I'm just pointing out that your explanation of "what really happens" doesn't necessarily hold.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: and what it reading in this case?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's impossible to say without additional experiments.  The observed behavior is consistent with passing the arguments on the stack, but it would also (for example) be consistent with the ARM calling conventions (where the args would be passed partially on the stack and partially in register), or any number of other situations.

Comment: @Stephen Cannon: I'm tempted to think that varargs have to be passed on the stack otherwise printf won't "know" where the parameters are. For example integers could be in normal registers while floating point could be in the FPU stack or SSE register. So basically it would wreck havoc on the calling convention unless everything is just thrown on the stack. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Mysticial: On OS X or Linux on x86_64, even va_args are passed in register (I'm not certain about the Windows ABI).  I know of several other platforms that do similar things.  They needn't be placed on the stack; all that's required is that printf be able to figure out where to find them (either using the format string, or some other means).

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at what is going on at the bit level:

- You compute 9/5, both numbers `int` -> This evaluates to 1 (again `int`) (let's say 32 bits) which is:

  ```
  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
  ```
- You push it as argument of `printf`
- You tell printf to get 32 bits of data from arguments and print it as a floating point number.
- `printf` reads that number I wrote above and prints it as if it was encoded with IEEE 754. The result is almost 0.

You can see [here](http://www.ajdesigner.com/fl_ieee_754_word/ieee_32_bit_word.php) the conversion:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

evaluates to

```
1.4012984e-45
```

---

As to why

```
printf("%f %f %d %d\n", (float)9/5, 4, sizeof(float), sizeof(int));
```

doesn't produce what you expect, the reason is that the argument `4` is an `int`, which is 4 bytes (on your machine). Due to argument promotion, `%f` expects a **double** which is 8 bytes. It's the same problem as above.

Comment: but when i use float b = 9/5 and then print the value of b, why i does not do the same. Its printing 5 in that case. Can you please explain !!

Comment: 5?! That's impossible. You need to show me a piece of code that does that and I'll tell you

Answer (score 0):

Using incorrect format specifiers inside `printf` is UB.

```
 printf("%f %f %zu %d\n", (float)9/5, 4.0, sizeof(float), sizeof(int));
```

gives the correct output.

Comment: 9/5 is 1, you're thinking 5/9.  The type mismatch is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

If you build with GCC, you should turn on all the warnings with `-Wall` *and* read them carefully.

The reason you get "strange" output is that you've violated `printf`s preconditions (passing arguments whose types do not match the format spec), and once you did, `printf` is free to do whatever it wants, including crashing, printing garbage, or melting your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

9/5 is an integer but you are trying to print it with "%f". It is the source of the problem. Switch to either 9.0/5 or "%d" and you will get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

(float)9/5 is casting only 9 not the result of 9/5. So the / operation isn't an integer operation at this point. (float)(9/5) will give the result 1.00000.

Try compiling with all warnings, and it will probably tell you a lot of what is wrong.

For example on a 64-bit linux system, compiling with gcc -Wall I get:

```
pf.c: In function ‘main’:
pf.c:6:2: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
pf.c:6:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
pf.c:6:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
```

As mentioned above you need the correct format specifiers. Using the right format specifiers and casting gives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%f %f %lu %lu\n",(float)(9/5),(float)4,sizeof(float),sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

gives:

```
snits@perelman:~/proj/c=>./pf
1.000000 4.000000 4 4
```